An instrument that sounds like flute but a bit lower
My music editor shows me that flute can't go so low (red color means this note is impossible on the flute):

I wonder which instrument I should use in this case to approximate the flute timbre as much as possible.

Well, that's just the standard concert flute. There are others in the concert flute family. And then you can get into flutes from other traditions or other fipple instruments like pipe organ.

While a flute can play the first six notes, it's unlikely to rise to the level of mezzo forte.  The image gives little context but implies that other instruments may be playing; if so, the flute is unlikely to be heard. You could just leave out the low notes or the entire phrase. Rimsky-Korsakov's Principles of Orchestration says, of tutti passages, "full wood-wind may be employed or not, according to the register and musical context...in the low register flutes will be unnecessary, and yet the passage can still be called tutti."

Also, if you don't have a good reason for using a key signature of seven sharps you should seriously consider using five flats instead; it's much easier to read, not least because it's much more common.  Both the choice of key signature and the out-of-range notes will tend to reduce the likelihood of your piece being performed.

@phoog - Thanks for this input.

LOL. Duuude. "The hyperbass flute [...] is pitched in C, four octaves below the concert flute[...] It is made of PVC and wood, its tubing is over 8 metres (26 ft) in length and its lowest note is C0 (16 Hz), below what is generally considered the range of human hearing. The only known example of the instrument is a prototype built for Italian flautist Roberto Fabbriciani by Francesco Romei, a Florentine craftsman." (From Andy's flute-family article.)

@FeRD - But that one doesn't sound like flute at all.

Consider the recorder family, too. #TeamRecorder

"The woodwind family of instruments includes, from the highest sounding instruments to the lowest, the piccolo, flute, oboe, English horn, clarinet, E-flat clarinet, bass clarinet, bassoon and contrabassoon."

@Mazura yes, but an oboe sounds less like a flute than does a bigger flute :-)

Flutists can 3D-print a little plastic extension to stick on the end of the B footjoint to lower the B to an A# while leaving all other notes unchanged, so technically this passage is possible, with that extension. I have one myself that works pretty well.
Otherwise, this register would be well suited to be played by an alto flute, which is pitched a perfect fourth lower than the standard C flute.

Wow, ingenious.  How would flutists do it before 3D printing?  Do metal extensions available to be purchased, if they don't want to use an alto flute?

There are longer footjoints, but they are very rare. If I recall correctly, Sankyo makes one down to low A natural.

@GratefulDisciple a lathe and suitable stock material. In fact I suspect that many more flautists (or flute repairers) would opt for traditional techniques and materials than for 3D printing.

Write the same passage for alto flute.  You would need to transpose the part (the alto flute sounds a perfect fourth lower than it's written).  Check with your ensemble first of course -- many flute players will not have an alto flute.
